# I want to split a dataframe column based on character length 3 into rows . How to do that in pyspark ?I know we can use explode and split

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have a data frame, and the String can have anything Alphabets ,numbers, symbols or  white spaces in between them :

```
Id | details
1  | ASD,GR D!G&HIK-HGD+TD
```

Expected output :

```
Id | details
1  |ASD
1  |,GR
1  | D!
1  |G&H
1  |IK-
1  |HGD
1  |+TD
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`split`**, **`regexp_replace`** functions.

**`Example:`**

```
df =spark.createDataFrame([(1,'ASDGRDGHIKHGDTD')],['id','details'])
df = df.withColumn("details", split(regexp_replace("details", "([a-zA-Z]{3})(?!$)", r"$1,"),",")).select("id",explode("details").alias("details"))

#result
#id details
#1  ASD
#1  GRD
#1  GHI
#1  KHG
#1  DTD
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `regexp_extract_all` in spark sql, so simply use this.

```
df.withColumn('details', f.explode(f.expr('regexp_extract_all(details, "(.{3})")'))) \
  .show()

+---+-------+
| id|details|
+---+-------+
|  1|    ASD|
|  1|    ,GR|
|  1|     D!|
|  1|    G&H|
|  1|    IK-|
|  1|    HGD|
|  1|    +TD|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: But I have string with special characters as well , it can have any symbols, whitespace ,etc. How to handle it with regex ?

Comment: replace [] block to .